# Use Remote Transactional MSMQ with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, msmq

I use MSMQ from WCF by `NetMsmqBinding` in remote transactional queue on windows server 2008.
The write is OK but it can't read when `ExactlyOne` property is set to true.
I want the queue to retry when it fails with an exception.

1. How a message can be read in a private remote queue?
2. How can I make the queue to retry when it fails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more info about "can't read"? Does it throw an exception or do you get any other error messages?

Comment: I see the message remain in the queue, I not see any error, maybe I don't know where to find it.     When the exactlyOnce property set to false, the message had read from the queue but on exeption, the message lost and not return to queue.

Comment: Hi,  I add exeption to my debuging and the error that I get is that:  "Additional information: An error occurred when converting the 'xxx\private$\yyy' queue path name to the format name: The queue path name specified is invalid. (-1072824300, 0xc00e0014). All operations on the queued channel failed. Ensure that the queue address is valid. MSMQ must be installed with Active Directory integration enabled and access to it is available."

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 3 years too late, but I was facing the same issue, and the following MSDN document helped me solve it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700128(v=vs.85).aspx

Distributed transaction coordinator should be configured to allow inbound/outbound connections on both the servers.